# Endless loop after account password change

Tags: google-account

I recently changed my Google account password, logging myself out of my Android tablet. It shows an alert of "account action required". Tapping the alert brings me to a page with "Verify that it's you. You were signed out of your Google Account. Sign in again to continue.". Tapping next brings me to the password prompt, but before I have the chance to input my password (even pasting from clipboard) the input loses focus and a loading spinner appears for a few seconds and I'm redirected to the "Verify that it's you" page.

I couldn't remove the account, probably because it's the only account on the device.

What can I do to get my account signed in again?

Comment: How old is the used Android device (which Android version is running)? Android can be used without any accounts installed, so that you can't remove the account may indicate that the phone has other problems.